# ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class... Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I start to use Symfony about 5-7 days ago, if my question is very simple, sorry, but I can't find a solution of my problem.
I've created 2 form classes - UserType and ClientType. Difference between them is that in ClientType form exists few additional fields.
Here is Usertype class:

```
namespace Acme\Gyvfiles\GyvefileBundle\Form\Type;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
    $builder->add('name', 'text');
    $builder->add('username', 'text');
    $builder->add('email', 'email', array(
        'attr' => array('class'=>'email') ) );
    $builder->add('Password', 'repeated', array(
        'first_name'  => 'password',
        'second_name' => 'confirm',
        'type'        => 'password',
    ));
    $builder->add( 'roles', 'choice', array(
        'choices' => array('ROLE_SYSTEM_ADMIN' => 'System Administrator', 'ROLE_ACCOUNT_ADMIN' => 'Account Manager', 'ROLE_UPLOADER' => 'Uploader'),
        'mapped' => false ) );
    $builder->add('is_active', 'checkbox', array(
        'label'     => 'Active (user can log in)',
        'required'  => false,
    ));
    $builder->add('add_user', 'submit');
}

  public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
  {
      $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Acme\Gyvfiles\GyvefileBundle\Entity\User'
    ));
  }

  public function getName()
  {
    return 'user';
  }
}
```

And at last ClientType class. All the same, except this part:
**Update:**

```
<?php
namespace Acme\Gyvfiles\GyvefileBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class ClientType extends AbstractType
{
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
    $builder->add('name', 'text');
    $builder->add('username', 'text');
    $builder->add('email', 'email', array(
        'attr' => array('class'=>'email') ) );
    $builder->add('Password', 'repeated', array(
        'first_name'  => 'password',
        'second_name' => 'confirm',
        'type'        => 'password',
    ));
    $builder->add('address', 'text');
    $builder->add('telephone', 'text');
    $builder->add('internalContactName', 'text');telephone
    $builder->add( 'roles', 'checkbox', array(
        'choices' => array('label' => 'Client can upload', ),
        'required'  => false ) );
    $builder->add('is_active', 'checkbox', array(
        'label'     => 'Active (user can log in)',
        'required'  => false,
    ));
    $builder->add('add_client', 'submit');
  }

  public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
  {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Acme\Gyvfiles\GyvefileBundle\Entity\Client'
    ));
  }

  public function getName()
  {
    return 'client';
  }
}
```

And after this steps I've used Usertype class in user controller successfully with this statement:

```
 $objUser = new User();
 $objForm = $this->get( 'form.factory')->create( new UserType(), $objUser );
```

But when I tried to use ClientType in Client Controller with similar syntax:

**Update: ClientController**

```
use Acme\Gyvfiles\GyvefileBundle\Entity\Permission;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Util\StringUtils;

use Acme\Gyvfiles\GyvefileBundle\Entity\Client;
use Acme\Gyvfiles\GyvefileBundle\Form\Type\ClientType;

class ClientController extends Controller
{
  public function addclientAction()
  {
    $em = $this->get( 'doctrine' )->getEntityManager();
    $objClient = new Client();
    $objForm = $this->get( 'form.factory')->create( new ClientType(), $objClient );
    //$objForm->add('address', 'text');
    return $this->render( 'AcmeGyvfilesGyvefileBundle:Client:addclient.html.twig', array(
        'form'  =>  $objForm->createView(),
    ));
  }
}
```

appears Class not found exception.

"ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "ClientType" from namespace "Acme\Gyvfiles\GyvefileBundle\Form\Type" in C:\wamp\www\Symfony\src\Acme\Gyvfiles\GyvefileBundle\Controller\ClientController.php line 22. Do you need to "use" it from another namespace?"

Can anyone help my with this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only assume that you are calling `new ClientType` or the likes in your controller? If so, you should add `use Acme\Gyvfiles\GyvefileBundle\Form\Type\ClientType` just under your namespace declaration as otherwise it is trying to find the class `ClientType` in the same folder as the calling class.

If you are using namespaces then calling a class without a namespace or without it being declared as `use`'d means it is being called relatively (so in the same directory).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes,I am calling `new ClientType` in my controller. Statements before controller are like this `use Acme\Gyvfiles\GyvefileBundle\Entity\Client;
use Acme\Gyvfiles\GyvefileBundle\Form\Type\ClientType;` . But the classnotfoundexception still occured..

Comment: Please post the full code of your controller and your ClientType class.

Answer (score 8):

I just encountered the same issue. It was the wrong name of the file containing the "Type" class. It MUST be the same as the contained class.

**Edit:**

It's about PSR-0 autoloader. It tries to include file based on the namespace of needed class. So given `Acme\Gyvfiles\GyvefileBundle\Form\Type\ClientType` namespace there MUST be a `ClientType` class in the `{pathToSymfony}/Acme/Gyvfiles/GyvefileBundle/Form/Type/` folder declared with

```
namespace Acme\Gyvfiles\GyvefileBundle\Form\Type;
```

at the begining of the file.

That was the isue in my case. Hope it helps!

Comment: this is actually the real solution to the problem. I gave credits with a mere upvote ;) I may add for the sake of discussion that you may eventually solve the namespace/path discrepancy using require once explicitily

Answer (score 5):

I have encountered this as you described, but it went away when I took an underscore out of the class name I'm instantiating. You don't have an underscore in yours, but try changing the name anyway.

Answer (score 3):

For me helped `composer dump-autoload --optimize`, because previously I executed `composer dump-autoload --optimize`

Answer (score 1):

In your controller ( or in defautController-> indexAction-> of your bundle), if you use a render call with your bundle name like this:         "$this->render('MyBundle:Default:index.html.twig');"
you need to add a use Bundle like this : "use PathBundle\MyBundle as MyBundle at ";

Answer (score 0):

The time I got that error my entity was like the folowing:

```
/**
 * InspectionPlanting
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="inspectionplanting")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Pencode\ForestryBundle\Entity\ClientProfileRepository")
```

All I did was to change it to without including my repository:

```
/**
 * InspectionPlanting
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="inspectionplanting")
 * @ORM\Entity
```

The last one worked.
Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

When I had similar error:

Attempted to load class \"CreateImportJobHandler\" from namespace \"NG\Command\".\nDid you forget a \"use\" statement for another namespace?

I was having correct use statement in the class which was using CreateImportJobHandler, but in xml service configuration was bad.

Had to be

```
<parameter key="ng.command.handler.create_import_job_handler.class">NG\Command\Groups\CreateImportJobHandler</parameter>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a typo in class file name: filename was `Syncroniser` but the classname was `Synchronizer`.