# Owncloud 8.1 "myapp" sample, add a function to write to a file

Tags: php, owncloud

On Owncloud 8.1 using the owncloud command line, I create a new test app:

`ocdev startapp MyApp --email mail@example.com --author "Your Name" --description "My first app" --owncloud 8`

The app is working, I can add it in the owncloud control panel.

Now I'd like to write to a file, so I use one example from the owncloud documentation:
https://doc.owncloud.org/server/8.1/developer_manual/app/filesystem.html

[Edit] I started over and now, I don't know if I omitted something, but "myapp" comes with no "application.php" file. 
So I create it at /var/www/core/apps/myapp/appinfo/application.php :

```
<?php
namespace OCA\MyApp\AppInfo;

use \OCP\AppFramework\App;

use \OCA\MyApp\Storage\AuthorStorage;


class Application extends App {

    public function __construct(array $urlParams=array()){
        parent::__construct('myapp', $urlParams);

        $container = $this->getContainer();

        /**
         * Storage Layer
         */
        $container->registerService('AuthorStorage', function($c) {
            return new AuthorStorage($c->query('RootStorage'));
        });

        $container->registerService('RootStorage', function($c) {
            return $c->query('ServerContainer')->getRootFolder();
        });

    }
}
```

Then I create a file called /var/www/core/apps/myapp/storage/AuthorStorage.php with:

```
<?php
namespace OCA\MyApp\Storage;

class AuthorStorage {

    private $storage;

    public function __construct($storage){
        $this->storage = $storage;
    }

    public function writeTxt($content) {
        // check if file exists and write to it if possible
        try {
            try {
                $file = $this->storage->get('/myfile.txt');
            } catch(\OCP\Files\NotFoundException $e) {
                $this->storage->touch('/myfile.txt');
                $file = $this->storage->get('/myfile.txt');
            }

            // the id can be accessed by $file->getId();
            $file->putContent($content);

        } catch(\OCP\Files\NotPermittedException $e) {
            // you have to create this exception by yourself ;)
            throw new StorageException('Cant write to file');
        }
    }
}
```

The sample app already gives me a route to the index function in the pagecontroller.php

```
['name' => 'page#index', 'url' => '/', 'verb' => 'GET']
```

How do I call the function "writeTxt" from there?
Based on http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php
I tried:

```
use \OCA\MyApp\Storage\AuthorStorage;
```

and

```
public function index() {
//added part
$a = new AuthorStorage();
$a->writeTxt('test');    
//original part
$params = ['user' => $this->userId];
return new TemplateResponse('myapp', 'main', $params);  //templates/main.php

}
```

After running I get a "Class 'OCA\MyApp\Storage\AuthorStorage' not found at /var/www/core/apps/myapp/controller/pagecontroller.php#44"

Even with the help of  `use \OCA\MyApp\Storage\AuthorStorage;` ( [ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class... Symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20448767/classnotfoundexception-attempted-to-load-class-symfony) ) it doesn't seem to help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Time has gone by, so I'm posting an answer to my question for owncloud 9.

Here are the steps to a basic script with read, write, copy file ability.

"application.php" has definitively been removed from the example. It was not a bug.

Following:
https://doc.owncloud.org/server/9.0/developer_manual/app/startapp.html
Generate the demo "MyApp" app:

```
ocdev startapp MyApp --email mail@example.com --author "Your Name" --description "My first app" --owncloud 9
```

Edit the file myapp/controller/pagecontroller.php

```
<?php
/**
 * ownCloud - myapp
 *
 * This file is licensed under the Affero General Public License version 3 or
 * later. See the COPYING file.
 *
 * @author Your Name <mail@example.com>
 * @copyright Your Name 2016
 */

namespace OCA\MyApp\Controller;

use OCP\IRequest;
use OCP\AppFramework\Http\TemplateResponse;
use OCP\AppFramework\Http\DataResponse;
use OCP\AppFramework\Controller;
use OCP\Files\IRootFolder;
use OC\Files\Storage\Temporary;

class PageController extends Controller {

    private $userId;
    private $storage;
    private $userstorage;

    public function __construct($AppName, IRequest $request, IRootFolder $storage, $UserId){
    parent::__construct($AppName, $request);
    $this->storage = $storage;
    $this->userId = $UserId;

    $this->userstorage = $this->storage->get($this->userId.'/files/');

    }



    /**
     * CAUTION: the @Stuff turns off security checks; for this page no admin is
     *          required and no CSRF check. If you don't know what CSRF is, read
     *          it up in the docs or you might create a security hole. This is
     *          basically the only required method to add this exemption, don't
     *          add it to any other method if you don't exactly know what it does
     *
     * @NoAdminRequired
     * @NoCSRFRequired
     */
    public function index() {

    $listedudossier = $this->userstorage->getDirectoryListing();

    //list all items in the root directory
    //and copies the files in an directory called old
    //the directory "old" is not script created
    foreach ($listedudossier as $value) {

        if ( $value->getType() == 'file' ){
            $value->copy($this->userId.'/files/old/'.$value->getName());
            //also works
            //$value->copy($this->userstorage->getPath().'/old/'.$value->getName());    
        }


    }

    $params = ['listedudossier' => $listedudossier ];
    return new TemplateResponse('myapp', 'main', $params);  // templates/main.php

    }

    /**
     * Simply method that posts back the payload of the request
     * @NoAdminRequired
     */
    public function doEcho($echo) {


    //creates a file    
    $this->userstorage->newFile('myfile2.txt');

    //opens a file, adds inputbox content and saves the file
    $file = $this->userstorage->get('myfile.txt');
    $contenu = $file->getContent(); 
    $file->putContent($contenu.$echo);

    return new DataResponse(['echo' => $echo]);
    }



}
```

You also need to edit the myapp/templates/part.content.php

```
<p>Hello World <?php p($_['user']) ?></p>

<p><button id="hello">click me</button></p>

<p><textarea id="echo-content">
    Send this as ajax
</textarea></p>
<p><button id="echo">Send ajax request</button></p>

Ajax response: <div id="echo-result"></div>

<p>listedudossier:<p> <?php 
foreach ($_['listedudossier'] as $file) {

   echo "type:".$file->getType(); 
   echo "<p>";

   echo "nom:".$file->getName(); 
   echo "<p>";

   echo "modif:".$file->getMTime(); 
   echo "<p>";

}
```

From here you can test the code in a development environment:
https://github.com/owncloud/ocdev/blob/master/README.rst#installation